# OVH VPS doesn't allow connection

Tags: dns, forward, ovh, godaddy-api, domain-masking

I have a domain name at godaddy and I set it up so that it will redirect to my OVH VPS.

You should know that in godaddy it is possible to do the redirection in 2 ways.

1) - Redirection only (Forward only) and so once I go on my domain name (www.example.com) I am redirected to vpsXXXXX.ovh.net which is visible on the bar of my browser instead of www.exemple.com and I arrives on my site (web application installed on my vps) successfully

2) - Forward with masking, and here the difference is that vpsXXXX.ovh.net is not displayed in my navigation bar, it is still www.example.com which is displayed but my vps refuses to answer and i get this: `vps719806.ovh.net does not allow connection` .. on my browser.

What should I do to make OVH agree to answer?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding an A type dns record in my dns dashboard pointing to my vps @IP adress instead of using forward method.